# Set image that shows up when my web page is linked

Tags: html

When you paste a link on something like Facebook or Discord, there's this image that shows below it. For example, if I link something from the Google Play Store to discord, the image I set in the play console as "Feature Graphic" shows up.
How can I set this image on any HTML page?

I know I can set a favicon like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
```

Can I do something similar for what I described?

Comment: usually they read the og:image tag.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the link preview meta tags as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example Page">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/images/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="This is just an example page.">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/page.html">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

Comment: This is known as Open Graph and you can find more information here: https://ogp.me